# How can I recreate this shadow effect between the 2nd and 3rd area?

Tags: winforms

I need to replicate this window's bottom part to use in my own Form.

[image]

Comment: Do it like Action Center does it, use the Paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is override the painting of an existing control or create your own control. Personally, I'd override the painting of a `Panel` control, which would then be the panel for the entire bottom section of your window.

A Gradient Panel is a common requirement and there is a blog post for it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cfrazier/archive/2005/08/10/422179.aspx) (code provided below).

Obviously you don't want to paint a full gradient, but it demonstrates how the painting works on the control.

You can either paint a gradient using a smaller subset of the entire panel or paint using something like [`Graphics.DrawPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath) and draw your straight line at the correct colour.

---

**Blog Post Code** (to avoid dead links):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PostXING.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GradientPanel is just like a regular panel except it optionally  
    /// shows a gradient.
    /// </summary>
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(Panel))]
    public class GradientPanel : Panel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Property GradientColor (Color)
        /// </summary>
        private Color _gradientColor;
        public Color GradientColor {
            get { return this._gradientColor;}
            set { this._gradientColor = value;}
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property Rotation (float)
        /// </summary>
        private float _rotation;
        public float Rotation {
            get { return this._rotation;}
            set { this._rotation = value;}
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
                        if(e.ClipRectangle.IsEmpty) return; //why draw if non-visible?

            using(LinearGradientBrush lgb = new 
                           LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, 
                      this.BackColor, 
                      this.GradientColor, 
                      this.Rotation)){
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, this.ClientRectangle);
            }

                        base.OnPaint (e); //right, want anything handled to be drawn too.
        }
    }
}
```